# sql rowlock on select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, pessimistic-locking

I have an ASP.Net webpage where the user selects a row for editing. I want to use the row lock on that row and once the user finishes the editing and updates another user can edit that row i.e. How can I use rowlock so that only one user can edit a row?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't lock a row like that using DB engine locks.

Most other strategies would rely on keeping the connection open (such as sp_getapplock) and this is nonsensical in web apps.

Even if you set a flag on the row, what happens if the user simply closes the browser mid-edit?

I'd suggest using a timestamp/rowversion column to detect changes to the row in other sessions.

Comment: +1 definitely - don't even get into that "locking by yourself" mess - it's just not worth the trouble...

Comment: Thanks, I will go with timestamp method.

Comment: +1, I do this, when you load the data for the page get the complete datetime of the last change.  when you go to save the data include `AND LastChangeDate=.......` on the UPDATE, if rowcount=0 then I issue an error message about someone else has already changed that data.

Answer (score 5):

Here i am giving two set of sql to row lock during select statement.

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT *
FROM   authors AU
WITH   (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE  AU.au_id = '274-80-9391'

/* Do all your stuff here while the row is locked */

COMMIT TRAN
```

The `HOLDLOCK` hint politely asks SQL Server to hold the lock until you commit the transaction. The `ROWLOCK` hint politely asks SQL Server to lock only this row rather than issuing a page or table lock.

Be aware that if lots of rows are affected, either SQL Server will take the initiative and escalate to page locks, or you'll have a whole army of row locks filling your server's memory and bogging down processing.

### another one

```
SELECT id From mytable WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) WHERE id = 1
```

another good link i want to share with you on lock. `https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/`

thanks

Comment: +1 for answering the question I came here to find, but it doesn't answer the OP's question.  You can't open a transaction, allow user input on a web page, then commit the transaction.  The whole transaction has to be one call to the server.