# C# example of ROWLOCK on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, locking

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that contains a table of Items. Many users are viewing Items and can choose at any time to check out an available Item. I want to have a simple locking scheme where the user clicks an Item, the server then acquires a ROWLOCK, checks if the item is checked out already (reads the row), checks it out if available (updates the row), and then frees up the lock.

I have not been able to find any code examples showing how to do this completely. Most examples focus on a single statement, not multiple statements.

Comment: Maybe you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767328/how-to-perform-a-row-lock

but i'm not sure it will work...

Comment: I read that, but it only covers a single statement. How do I ensure that the lock persists through the entire transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

[sql rowlock on select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674018/sql-rowlock-on-select-statement)

at work, we do that through a program that runs on the server.

All requests go through this program.